# Wagtail proper way to add settings to a stream block

Tags: django, wagtail

say we have a stream block as:

```
class CarouselStreamBlock(StreamBlock):

    image = StructBlock([
        ('file', ImageChooserBlock()),
        ('caption', RichTextBlock( classname='caption'  )),

    ])
```

We have a scenario that we want to give the admin editor the ability of setting each carousel's width, height, bgcolor etc...

I have tried to add that settings as another struct block named to the carousel itself with a max_length of 1.

```
  class CarouselStreamBlock(StreamBlock):
     settings = StructBlock([
                ('align', blocks.ChoiceBlock(choices=[('center', 'Center'), ('right', 'Right'), ('left', 'Left'), ], default='center', max_length=10) ),
                ('width', blocks.IntegerBlock(required=False ) ),
                ('background_color', blocks.CharBlock(max_length=10, required=False))
            ], icon='cog' )

    image = StructBlock([
                ('file', ImageChooserBlock()),
                ('caption', RichTextBlock( classname='caption'  )),

            ])
```

But I am not satisfied with this way. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

A [StreamBlock](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13/topics/streamfield.html#streamblock) consists of a sequence of sub-blocks of different types. In other words, all the blocks are going to be siblings of each others, when really the settings should be part of the image block or the carousel block itself.

If each image needs its own settings, you can do something like this:

```
class CustomImage(blocks.StructBlock):
    file = ImageChooserBlock()
    caption = RichTextBlock(classname='caption')

    align = blocks.ChoiceBlock(
        choices=[('center', 'Center'), ('right', 'Right'), ('left', 'Left')],
        default='center',
        max_length=10,
    )
    width = blocks.IntegerBlock(required=False)
    background_color = blocks.CharBlock(max_length=10, required=False)

class CarouselStreamBlock(blocks.StreamBlock):
    image = CustomImage()

class MyPage(Page):
    carousel = StreamField(CarouselStreamBlock())
```

If however the settings are shared between all the images, you can do something like this instead:

```
class CustomImage(blocks.StructBlock):
    file = ImageChooserBlock()
    caption = RichTextBlock(classname='caption')

class CarouselStreamBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    align = blocks.ChoiceBlock(
        choices=[('center', 'Center'), ('right', 'Right'), ('left', 'Left')],
        default='center',
        max_length=10,
    )
    width = blocks.IntegerBlock(required=False)
    background_color = blocks.CharBlock(max_length=10, required=False)

    images = blocks.ListBlock(CustomImage())

class MyPage(Page):
    carousel = StreamField(CarouselStreamBlock())
```